# Changing Default JDK On Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk, 20.10

I'm having trouble changing the default version of Java on Ubuntu 20.10.

I want to change the default version of Java JDK from Graal to OpenJDK 13.

I start by checking the default version:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 20.1.0 (build 11.0.7+10-jvmci-20.1-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 20.1.0 (build 11.0.7+10-jvmci-20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I change the version as follows, selecting OpenJDK version 13:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 4 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1211      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/graalvm/bin/java                    4         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
* 3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1211      manual mode
  4            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
```

If I check version again it's still saying the version is GraalVM:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 20.1.0 (build 11.0.7+10-jvmci-20.1-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 20.1.0 (build 11.0.7+10-jvmci-20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
$
```

I've restarted my machine, but the GraalVM is still the default.

Why is the version not changing?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the `~/.bashrc` and noticed that I'd added a path to the Graal `/bin` folder to the PATH.

Once I removed that, I opened a new terminal, re-ran the `update-alternatives`, and saw that the version was set properly.

Comment: You can use `type java` to see which binary is invoked.  This would have told you pretty early you weren’t using the system Java binary.